# EventBus vs singleton

Tags: java, android, eventbus

Скажите можно в eventbus сделать `subscribe` внутри класса `singleton`, т.е. я делаю `eventbus.getDefault.register(this)` и далее создаю `singleton` и хочу, чтобы выполнился `subscribe` на определенный `event`?

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так, у меня работает

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance;

    private Singleton() {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }    
        return instance;
    }

    public void onEvent(Event1 event1) {
        //handle event
        Log.e("sdcsd", "event1event1event1event1");
    }
}
```

gradle

```
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
```

Comment: да, не помогает

Comment: onevent не вызывается

Comment: @Contact попробуйте новое решение, должно работать

Answer (score 1):

все как всегда проще, выше приведенный код верен, только регистрация должна происходить все static метода

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/75435)

Comment: @Denis Да нет, это именно что ответ, хотя качество и хромает.